# Restrict live an input field comparing it to another field

Tags: javascript, php, timepicker

I have a php page and these two inputs fields. My goal is to check if the second input is equal to first input (live) and make an error msg. The code i have so far is this:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="timepicker1"              
    data-target-input="nearest">

    <input type="text"     
    class="form-control datetimepicker-input"
    data-target="#timepicker1"

    name="FirstDate" id="FirstDate"  />

</div>
<div class="input-group date" id="timepicker2"  
                                                                
    data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" onclick="CheckForErrors()"

    class="form-control datetimepicker-input"
    data-target="#timepicker2"

    name="SecondDate" id="SecondDate"  />

</div>
```

In the end of the php i have a Javascript checking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckForErrors() {
      // Check if First Time is equal with second Time
      if (FirstDate == SecondDate) {
        alert("Error MSG!");
      }
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

Its not working, as u understand. Any help ?
PS. I'm a begginer so please be patient :D

Comment: As per the code, You are using variables directly without taking their input value. Also Use On Change event instead of Click event on Second text box. You need to Write JS code Like: function CheckForErrors() {
      // Check if First Time is equal with second Time
      var FirstDate document.getElementById("FirstDate").value;
      var SecondDate document.getElementById("SecondDate").value;
      if (FirstDate == SecondDate) {
        alert("Error MSG!");
      }
      return false;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a little bit your code. First i remove the Tag inline assign of an eventListener (bad practice). Then i check on every `keyup` the fields. It works on both directions. Means if you start typing in the second field, it will check immediately with field one. and vice versa.

```js
box = document.getElementById('doubleChecker');
box.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const i1 = document.getElementById('timepicker1').children[0]
  const i2 = document.getElementById('timepicker2').children[0]
  console.log(i1.value , i2.value)  
  if (i1.value == i2.value) {
    alert("Error MSG!");
    return false;
  }  
  
});
```

```html
<div id="doubleChecker">
<div class="input-group date" id="timepicker1"      
    data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" 
    class="form-control datetimepicker-input"
    data-target="#timepicker1"
    name="FirstDate" id="FirstDate"  />
</div>

<div class="input-group date" id="timepicker2"                                                                  
    data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text"
    class="form-control datetimepicker-input"
    data-target="#timepicker2"

    name="SecondDate" id="SecondDate"  />

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: First window is the script and its first because it should be over the php code ? Because it still wont work to me...

Comment: @user14631143 you dont have any PHP in your code? You have html and javascript. probably you generate the html with php. but it dont effect the javascript check. the workflow would be: php generate html and send it to the client. the client start typing. javascript check immediatly these two fields. if equal the show the alert and other thing to avoid that the user can send the form. if he can pass the javscript chech you have to check on server side if these fields double again.

Comment: @user14631143 you got it?

Comment: Nope. I've made a more simple examplel to understand whats wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You can get input values by document.querySelector({selector}).value . So your code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckForErrors() {
        // Check if First Time is equal with second Time
        if (document.querySelector("#FirsDate").value == document.querySelector("#SecondDate").value) {
            alert("Error MSG!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Also you are doing your check and if its true you display error message. But your function always returns false. Add return true inside your check to stop further execution.